# Omnetpp cannot install on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, omnet++

This is just a note of my experience which I want to share to other newbies of OMNetpp. Don't waste your precious time on installment.

The official document of omnetpp 5.5.1 said it support multiple OSs, including ubuntu 18.04. But I encountered tons of errors when I install it on Ubuntu 18.04. (Tens of libs OMNetpp relies on are older than those already have on Ubuntu 18.04. So it recommend me to downgrade those libs to older version, which is unacceptable to me. Because I cannot know which other apps rely on those libs asking for newest version.)

I tried to install it on Mac Mojave (10.14), Win 10, Ubuntu 18.04. Only successfully installed on Ubuntu 16.04 smoothly. So I will just recommend to use it on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ does support Ubuntu 18.04. A lot of people are using it on various OS-es you've mentioned. If you have installation errors, you should probably provide logs.

Comment: When I tried it on Ubuntu 18.04. Almost all libs it rely on are older. So I need to reinstall tens of libs. That unacceptable. What if other apps need newer version libs? And that's not friendly to beginner. So I won't recommend Ubuntu 18.04.